Excel lookup by column name
Here is a scenario -
I have quantity table like this



100
200




$1
$3


$2
$4



I have more columns with other values like 300, 400, 500 and so on. Also, each row has a name associated but I am new to the platform so dont know how to format it. For example, row 1 is alex, row 2 is David. Now in a different sheet, if someone enters name and quantity, for example, 250 and David, then I want to go to the table above, find the row for david (which is row 2) and the column thats either closest or more than the quantity, which will be column 3 here with 300, and then list the $ value. I know how to xlookup David and $ value, but I dont know how to pick the right column. Can someone help provide some guidance on this please?

Here's one method:
Make your Quantity table a real table, then use structured references and INDEX...XMATCH.
In the below formula, H2 contains the selected name, and I2 the quantity.
Also note the double unary in front of Quantity[#Headers]. When you create a table, the headers are all turned into text strings, so to get a proper match we must convert them back to numbers.
=INDEX(
    Quantity,
    XMATCH(H2, Quantity[Name]),
    XMATCH(I2, --Quantity[#Headers], 1, 1)
)


There are a variety of other formulas that can also work, eg:
=CHOOSECOLS(
    FILTER(Quantity, Quantity[Name] = H2),
    XMATCH(I2, --Quantity[#Headers], 1)
)

or even nested XLOOKUP's, but I think the first is the easiest to understand.
